# Decimal validation in server side textbox using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, c#-4.0, decimal

I use this code for decimal validation.It was working fine.but it allow to enter the alphabets into the text box. when i exit from the text box then only  the error message will show nearby textbox.I need,**if i press the alphabets the text box doesn't allow to enter the text box** , how to do this?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtNumber" 
                    runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"
                        ErrorMessage="Please enter only numbers">
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Javascript:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" onkeypress="AllowOnlyNumeric(event);" 
   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function AllowOnlyNumeric(e) {
    if (window.event) // IE 
    {
        if (((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) & e.keyCode != 8) & e.keyCode != 46) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;

        }
    }
    else { // Fire Fox
        if (((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) & e.which != 8) & e.which != 46) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to prevent more than one dot symbols in that textbox?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `CompareValidator`, you don't really need to use regex:

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
      ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
      ErrorMessage="Please enter a numberical value." ForeColor="Red"
      Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer">!
</asp:CompareValidator>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can also do this on the server just using `TryParse()`:

```
int x = 0;
bool valid = Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out x);
if(!valid)
   {
        //inform the user
   }
```

Comment: Great, now I'm going to be late for work because I'm answering questions on SO. Whelp, gotta run.

Comment: You probably want `double` rather than `integer`. And does this _really_ answer the question, i.e. does it _stop the user typing_ an invalid number instead of just telling them after the textbox loses focus?